# compare two data frames and delete columns based on lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

df1:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   63  9   56  23  41  0
1   40  35  69  98  47  45
2   51  95  55  36  10  34
3   25  11  67  83  49  89
4   91  10  43  73  96  95
5   2   47  8   30  46  9
6   37  10  33  8   45  20
7   40  88  6   29  46  79
8   75  87  49  76  0   69
9   92  21  86  91  46  41
```

df2:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

I want to delete Columns in df1 based on values in df2(lookup table). wherever df2 has 1 I have to delete that column in df1.

so my final output should be like.

```
    A   B   C   F
0   63  9   56  0
1   40  35  69  45
2   51  95  55  34
3   25  11  67  89
4   91  10  43  95
5   2   47  8   9
6   37  10  33  20
7   40  88  6   79
8   75  87  49  69
9   92  21  86  41
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `len(df1.columns) == len(df2.columns)`:

```
df1.loc[:, ~df2.loc[0].astype(bool).values]

    A   B   C   F
0  63   9  56   0
1  40  35  69  45
2  51  95  55  34
3  25  11  67  89
4  91  10  43  95
5   2  47   8   9
6  37  10  33  20
7  40  88   6  79
8  75  87  49  69
9  92  21  86  41
```

---

If the columns aren't the same, but `df2` has a subset of columns in `df1`, then

```
df1.reindex(df2.columns[~df2.loc[0].astype(bool)], axis=1)
```

Or with `drop`, similar to @student's method:

```
df1.drop(df2.columns[df2.loc[0].astype(bool)], axis=1)
```

```
    A   B   C   F
0  63   9  56   0
1  40  35  69  45
2  51  95  55  34
3  25  11  67  89
4  91  10  43  95
5   2  47   8   9
6  37  10  33  20
7  40  88   6  79
8  75  87  49  69
9  92  21  86  41
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping, what if the columns are different.

Comment: @BhanuTez See edit. As long as the number of columns are the same, this'll work.

Answer (score 1):

columns can do `intersection`

```
df1[df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns[~df2.iloc[0].astype(bool)])]
Out[354]: 
    A   B   C   F
0  63   9  56   0
1  40  35  69  45
2  51  95  55  34
3  25  11  67  89
4  91  10  43  95
5   2  47   8   9
6  37  10  33  20
7  40  88   6  79
8  75  87  49  69
9  92  21  86  41
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `drop` to drop the columns:

```
remove_col = df2.columns[(df2 == 1).any()] # get columns with any value 1
df1.drop(remove_col, axis=1, inplace=True) # drop the columns in original dataframe
```

Or, in one line as:

```
df1.drop(df2.columns[(df2 == 1).any()], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be an easily understandable solution:

```
df1.loc[:,df2.loc[0]!=1]
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   F
0  63   9  56   0
1  40  35  69  45
2  51  95  55  34
3  25  11  67  89
4  91  10  43  95
5   2  47   8   9
6  37  10  33  20
7  40  88   6  79
8  75  87  49  69
9  92  21  86  41
```

`loc` can be used for selecting rows or columns with a boolean or conditional lookup : https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/